# Why is this surface so weird?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]

This is a simple object with a coloring material. The image below has no material.
I don't change any material parameters except the color. Why one of the faces look reflective?

Source File [image]

Comment: Maybe it is not reflectivity but rather a problem of normals or bad shading, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faces' textures are not changed and they are not reflective, merely shaded smooth. Just go to editmode, select and right-click the odd-looking faces, and click "shade flat" to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to BSE.

There are two issues with your model:

1. Some of the normals are incorrect
2. You have 80 sets of vertices that are overlapping eachother.

Please try the following steps:

- Select your object and press Tab to enter edit mode.
- Press A to select all vertices in the model.
- Press M to remove any overlapping vertices.
- Press Shift+N to recalculate your normals to the outside.

I had a look at your file and tried the above steps but unfortunately the issue persists. Therefore, I did the following:

- Go to top view (Numpad 7)
- In object mode, select your object
- Press Shift+S > Cursor to Selected
- Set your Pivot Point to 3D cursor (Shorcut: fullstop key)
- Tab into edit mode.
- Hover over the problematic geometry, and press L to select it:

[image]

- Delete this geometry
- Select the geometry opposite:

[image]

- Press Shift+D to duplicate, then R to rotate and 180 for 180 degrees.

I believe this should leave you with what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already merge the vertices. But the key of the problem is the shadow that another answer metions.

Comment: Yeah I saw the answer from Bentley. I guess the problem was much more simple than I thought! Glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: Simply check Auto smooth Normals under Object Data > Normals (green triangle icon).